# Why do HttpEntity and HttpResponse not report content length properly?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some fairly straightforward code that's making a call to a URL, getting the response, and, if there's an entity, transferring the entity down.

The catch comes when I added a test of the entity content length. I can run the call through a proxy and see that the Content-Length header is getting set properly:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="something.zip";
Content-Length: 12390600
Content-Type: application/zip
```

So in my code I check that:

```
HttpResponse response = _client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

if (entity != null && entity.getContentLength() > 0) {
    handleEntity(entity);
}
```

If I look at the response, all of the expected headers are there *except* for the content length. When I check the entity object, it returns -1 for the **getContentLength()** call. In the documentation, if your content length exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE it'll return a negative number, but [that's not the case here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE)

So I've just removed this check for now but I'd really like to understand that what means in this context. The docs add a caveat that it will return the content length "if known" but in this case it appears that it SHOULD be known.

Thanks for any insight into what's going on here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are mixing up HTTP message content length and that of individual MIME body parts in a multipart content body

Comment: So the HTTP message content length includes the MIME boundary phrases and the size of the encoded content, etc.? Is there any way then to translate that back to the size of the actual message payload, so that I can know, e.g., the posted Zip content is 12MB or whatever?

Comment: @SpankyQuigman I do not think this is possible if the message is chunk coded

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. I've modified the code to not expect that value for the entity and it now just looks to see whether there's an entity or not.